# AngularJS google chart com dados dinamicos

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-charts, angularjs-scope

Exemplo de como está meu codigo

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/hMnKAzjbkQzHWjL5p6KX?p=previewangularjs
```

Eu recebo os dados da webService e organizo deste jeito.

```
var avaliacoes_descTipo = [];
var avaliacoes_quantidade = [];

angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) { 
                this.push(key + ': ' + value);
                avaliacoes_descTipo[key] = value.descTipo;
                avaliacoes_quantidade[key] = value.quantidade;
 }, log_avaliacoes);
```

Porém não estou conseguindo colocar dinâmico os valores, colocar um array, não sei, então to colocando fixo, como o exemplo abaixo.

```
**{w: [
                     {V: avaliacoes_descTipo [1]},
                     {V: avaliacoes_quantidade [1]}
                 ]}
                 {w: [
                     {V: avaliacoes_descTipo [2]},
                     {V: avaliacoes_quantidade [2]}
                 ]}
]};**
```

Preciso da ajuda para deixar dinâmico, por foreach, qualquer maneira que eu não precise ficar colocando o índice nele.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta fazer da seguinte forma:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   var avaliacoes_descTipo = ["1", "12", "13"];
   var avaliacoes_quantidade = [1,2,3];
   var val = [];
   var i;
   var val1 = [];
$scope.avaliacoes = {};

for (i = 0; i < avaliacoes_descTipo.length; i++) {
  val = {c: [
    {v: avaliacoes_descTipo[i]},
    {v: avaliacoes_quantidade[i]}
  ]};

  val1.push(val);
}

$scope.avaliacoes.type = "PieChart";

$scope.onions = [
  {v: avaliacoes_descTipo[0]},
  {v: avaliacoes_quantidade[0]}
];

$scope.avaliacoes.data = {"cols": [
  {id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string"},
  {id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number"}
], "rows":
  val1

};

$scope.avaliacoes.options = {
  'title': '',
  'legend' : {'position': 'bottom'}
};

});
```

Comment: Otima resposta!  funcionou perfeitamente! obrigado, muito obrigado!